# How to put a link in HTML that opens Viber/Whatsapp/iMessages/Facetime in a smart phone?

Tags: android, iphone, html, smartphone, whatsapp

I want to find a way so that people browsing a website from a smart phone can contact the company via any of the preferred methods.

Doing it for Skype is easy... but what about Viber/Whatsapp/iMessages/FaceTime?

Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible.

You have to know url scheme which this apps registered for themselves. Of cause, if they did it.

For example Facebook application uses `fb://` scheme. For other applications look through their ipa files (main plist files)